# Json path doesn't match. Expected sql.Date, found lang.String (RestAssure)

Tags: java, json, rest, rest-assured

I have a problem with deserialisation of response body. I need sql.Date but in fact I get lang.String
Help me to correctly setup my RestAssure, please.

Here is how my `RestAssure.config` looks:

```
RestAssured.config =
    RestAssuredConfig.config().objectMapperConfig(objectMapperConfig()
    .gsonObjectMapperFactory((aClass, s) -> 
    new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").create()));
```

Here is my test:

```
given() 
       .contentType("application/json") 
       .when() .get("some url") .then()
       .assertThat().body("birthday", response ->
       equalTo(Date.valueOf("2016-06-07")))
```

And such exception I got:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
 1 expectation failed. 
 JSON path birthday doesn't match. 
 Expected: <1994-12-30> Actual: 1994-12-30
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `extract()` on response to get needed value and convert your string to whatever you wish.

```
Response r = given() 
   .contentType("application/json") 
   .when() .get("some url") 
   .then()
   .extract();
```